# Pygame couldn't open image

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to load an image from a folder. then blit it to 0,0
The path i'm trying to load from is :  ".\media\img\bk\spaceport.png". 
the script is in the root of the folder. 
i'm using windows if that matters

```
sWIDTH = 800
sHEIGHT = 600
class IMGLOAD():
    def BAK(ImageTobeUsed):
        b1 = pygame.image.load(ImageTobeUsed)
        background = pygame.transform.scale(b1,( sWIDTH, sHEIGHT))
        window.blit(background,(0,0))

IMGLOAD.BAK(".\media\img\bk\bedroom.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a [raw-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) for the file path:

```
IMGLOAD.BAK(r".\media\img\bk\bedroom.jpg")
```

`\b` is a special character in Python string literals (it represents a backspace).  Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> '\b'
'\x08'
>>> r'\b'
'\\b'
>>> print('x\by')
y
>>> print(r'x\by')
x\by
>>>
```

Comment: pygame.error: Couldn't open media\img\bd\spaceport.png
>>>

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct?  You did `img\bk` in your question but are doing `img\bd` here.  Make sure this is correct and also try replacing `.` with the full path to the image file.

Comment: that was just a typo when I was transfering.

Comment: I changed the file to something w/out special charters and it worked. I changed it to aaa.